# PHP accessing functions within a function

Tags: php, class, function

I'm really new to PHP classes and I was just wondering how to access functions within a PHP Class.

For example:

```
<?PHP
$cn = "myClass";
$myClass = new $cn;

class myClass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        doSomething(); // ?
    }
    private function doSomething() {
        echo "doSomething accessed!<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

How would I access `doSomething()` within the class? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that you're **too lazy** to spend at least few minutes browsing [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) where you could get it either from `Example #1 Simple Class definition` (with a bit of imagination) or take a look at first user comment whe you could find `$this->existenceRequirement();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `$this`:

```
<?PHP
$cn = "myClass";
$myClass = new $cn;

class myClass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->doSomething(); // ?
    }
    private function doSomething() {
        echo "doSomething accessed!<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

*The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object.*